# Are there any playable Twilight Imperium 2 player variants?

Tags: variants, twilight-imperium, twilight-imperium-3rd-edition, two-player

I love TI 3rd edition, but can't always get together 3 players willing to commit the amount of time it takes to play a game.

Are there any 2 player variants of this game?

Answer (score 4):

There is no *official* 2-player variant; the game just wasn't designed for it.

But as always, the internet provides.  Various fans have proposed two-player rule sets.

The [Roland Wood variant](http://www.preeminent.org/steve/games/ti3/ti3demo/2-player/home/) is probably the most commonly used, building on earlier suggestions by other players.

(There was another popular version in the "Shattered Expansion", but I can no longer find a live link.)

Comment: Personally I don't actually *recommend* 2-player TI; like Cosmic Encounter, it's one of those games where the correct objective of a two-player game is "find a third player".  However, some people find it to be a blast; your personal taste may vary as always.

Comment: IT's worth trying, I don't think I'll get a chance to try it for a wee while though as I'm about to go travelling, and TI is not a travel friendly game.

Answer (score -1):

After trying out normal games, princess, and automata, we came to what plays fastest/simplest and balances the races altogether with flow, so no one gets too pwned. Introducing:

IDLE, NOT SO IDLE, BOT

**SETUP**: Bot has all his units set up on the board (no war suns or flagships), home system only having max PDS and 1 space dock -

- reinforcing all BOT's systems (1/3 of map if one BOT), with heavier fleet towards home system, placement ignores all rules and is symetric.

**MISCELANIOUS**: After both players pick 2 strategy cards each, they each pick 1 for BOT.

**MISCELANIOUS**: BOT plays the top strategy card for players to have opportunity to use it's secondary effect on his "turn". Bot does not benefit from its primary ability.

**MISCELANIOUS**: BOT always has maximum amount of commodities and no victory points.

**ACTION PHASE**: Player trade - Active player can trade any amount of commodities with BOT, if spending 1 "BOT influence token" per commodity altogether;

**ACTION "command bot"**: Choose one system with BOT's units, pay "BOT influence token"s for each of his SPACE units in that system -

- activate adjacent system containing any non-BOT units, move in, attack, capture with all BOT's space and ground forces. Player can then PRODUCE any amount of BOT's casualties in his previous location.

**TRADE CARD**: When a player plays trade card, and chooses BOT to replenish commodities, BOT looses all his commodities to the void, and replenishes.

**DIPLOMACY CARD**: Alternatively a player can use it to "command bot" without "BOT influence token" price (production costs would still apply).

**STATUS PHASE**: Before anything, Each player gets 2 "BOT influence token"s. Loosing player gets additional token, commodity and trade good per VP difference.

**AGENDA PHASE**: BOT votes yes for himself, and his adjecent planet to home towards direction of speaker; His influence is a sum of both players VP

**AGENDA PHASE**: Player can bid any amount of tokens any amount of times for all BOT's influence towards to be of his desire, even when denied from voting; No affect on tie.

**AGENDA PHASE**: Players can ADD votes any amount of times, until both agree that the decision is final.

***Use anything you like for "BOT influence token", would it be m&m's or bottlecaps or tokens from another game.***